# How to abstract trees as triangles in tikz?

Tags: tikz-trees, tikz-arrows

Basically, I'd like to draw something like the following figure where t1 is a tree and be able to connect their roots (black nodes) with edges. Is there a simple way to do it ?
[image]

Comment: Have you ever used TikZ before?

Comment: Just to draw regular nodes and edges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I don't know where you are heading, I suggest to start with plain `tikz`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{root/.style={circle,draw,fill,inner sep=2 pt}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[root] (rootA) {};
  \node[root,xshift=3cm] (rootB) {};
  \draw (rootA) -- +(-1,-2) -- node[yshift=0.75cm]{$t_1$} +(1,-2) -- (rootA);
  \draw (rootB) -- +(-1,-2) -- node[yshift=0.75cm]{$t_1$} +(1,-2) -- (rootB);
  \draw[-stealth', shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm] (rootA) -- (rootB);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```